# How to call ffmpeg from Activity?

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I want to use ffmpeg to change the resolution of video.

However, i don't know how can i call ffmpeg executable from activity in android.

I am using eclipse and Windows 7

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please refer this link https://github.com/churnlabs/android-ffmpeg-sample

Answer (score 2):

You should follow basically this steps:

1. Build ffmpeg for android (http://bambuser.com/opensource)
2. Load the ffmpeg library (*.so) on your app
3. Use native calls (JNI) to call ffmpeg APIs

Comment: But how can i pass the command,I am really confused there. 
Command is like:-                                          
ffmpeg -i input.mpeg -s 320x240 output.mpeg

Comment: You won't use command line operations! You will have to open and process the file accordingly!

Comment: actually i need to do it through command line, this is exactly what the task is.